# Init containers nslookup issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a Init container in my kubernetes deployment file, I see that init containers are not able to verify the availability of services present in different namespaces using helm. below ns1 is a namespace

```
      initContainers:
        - name: init-service1 #here I cannot give init-service1.<namespace> as (.) is not allowd
          image: busybox
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nslookup service1.<namespace>; do echo waiting for service1.<namespace>; sleep 10; done;']
```

I tried the same with same namespace and it works perfectly fine with helm

Secondly the name of initcontainer should match the name of services I am looking up??

another problem is helm I cannot give the name as init-service1. as (.) is not allowed.

Any help is highly appreciayed

Comment: Are you getting an error you can share?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with multiples namespaces, you need to use a FQDN for reach your services:

> When you create a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/), it creates a corresponding [DNS entry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/). This entry is of the form `<service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local`, which means that if a container just uses `<service-name>` it will resolve to the service which is local to a namespace. This is useful for using the same configuration across multiple namespaces such as Development, Staging and Production. If you want to reach across namespaces, you need to use the fully qualified domain name (FQDN)

In your case: `service1.svc.myapp.svc.cluster.local`

> Secondly the name of initontainer should match the name of services I am looking up??

No. The `initContainer` name doesn't matter in this field, you could use what you want.

In your case it should work:

```
      initContainers:
        - name: my-init
          image: busybox:1.28
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nslookup service1.svc.myapp.svc.cluster.local; do echo waiting for service1.svc.myapp.svc.cluster.local; sleep 10; done;']
```

**References:**

[Understanding namespaces and DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/namespaces/#understanding-namespaces-and-dns)